# $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

It seems true.
I tried to show first that $f(A \cup B) \subseteq f(A) \cup f(B)$.

So, I start

(1) $f(x) \in f(A \cup B)$

(2) $x \in A \cup B$

(3) $x \in A \cup x \in B$

(4) $f(x) \in A \cup f(x) \in f(B)$

**However,** it does not seem to me that I can deduce (2) from (1).
Suppose $f(A) = f(B) = f(C) = D$ and $x \in C.$

It follows that $f(x) \in f(A \cup B) = D,$ but $x \not\in A \cup B.$

And, I cannot continue with my proof.

Where is my thinking wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: You cannot deduce (2) from (1) unless the function is injective...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
$$y\in f(A\cup B)$$
$\exists x\in A\cup B$ such that $y=f(x)$
$\Longrightarrow x\in A$ or $x\in B$
$\Longrightarrow f(x)\in f(A)$ or $f(x)\in f(B)$
$\Longrightarrow y\in f(A)\cup f(B)$

Hence proved

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Hey, Martund. Thank you very much. It does help!